# Extracting all entered characters from number input in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a basic GAS app designed to record and store data within a gSheet.

I'm trying to find the best way to delete a number that was previously recorded, by inputting another row with a "-" or "e" within the number input. But when I retrieve the .val() for either of those it shows as blank.

Is it possible to retrieve the actual text inputted or is it always converted to a number first?

Comment: Perhaps you can share your code because I haven't a clue as what your talking about.

Comment: There is a method to get the displayed value.  [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())  It returns a string.